# Check if the user and the password of a remote desktop are correct using c#

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, mstsc

Please I need help about how I can check if the user and the password are correct when login in a remote desktop.
I have already write this code to connect but what I really need it's just **check** if the login is **correct**.

This is my method:

I'm Using **MSTSC Lib**

```
public void test(string sr, string us, string pwd)
{   
    rdp.Server = sr;
    rdp.UserName = us;
    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
    secured.ClearTextPassword = pwd;
    rdp.Connect(); 

    MessageBox.Show(rdp.Connected.ToString());
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The validation must happen in the remote computers domain. Unless you are on the same domain as the remote computer there is no other way than trying to connect

Comment: I found an event -> OnLoginComplete it works for me :) this event happens when the login and the password are correct and the app's login into the computer ,thanks for your answer